# How to load a custom assembly automatically every time Visual Studio launched?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-library

I have a C# class library to make the works easier and I want to use it in my every project. So there must be an easy way to load it automatically as default on VS is opened and so I don't have to reference it again and again in my every project created. How can I do it?

Comment: You should make a project template.

Comment: So do you mean if a project template that has the assembly loaded exists, it will appear on the 'create new project' menu and by selecting it I will get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

1. If this project is stable version, you could add it to GAC like those .net framework dll. refer to below msdn article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac

2. Create a new project, add reference to above dll, and use File->Export Template --> Project to export a new project,
3. after that, restart Visual Studio, you should be able to see your own project template when you want to create new project.